# Rails: two radio selects on same source list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button

Wondering how to approach this... Best to look at the picture to visualize the, hopeful, UI for a form for choosing options in a list. Users need to be able to make a **first choice** and a **second choice** for each option. One and only one can be selected in each column, and for that matter, each row.

[image]

At first I thought, naturally, 2 radio button groups might work...but not sure how? Perhaps hidden `radio_button`s whose `value`s are manipulated via Javascript/JQuery in a `click` event on each div? Event should also check/handle "collisions" when user tries to select same option for both choices.

Or, would this perhaps be better with two hidden `collection_select`s...or even simpler, just two hidden text_fields...which javascript can populate with the ID of the selected option?

Or maybe I'm overlooking something more obvious.

I'm new(ish) to javascripting with Rails so looking for advice/validation.

Thanks.

Comment: can both choice for 'option B' possible?

Comment: no. you should only be able to check **one** box in each column *and* each row.

Comment: in that case what should happen when there is box selected from [row1 x col1] and for next choice user tries to select [row1x col2]. is it going to reset earlier selection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this is what your looking for:

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <p class="exclusiveSelection">
        Selection One
        <input type="radio" name="firstColumn"/>
        <input type="radio" name="secondColumn"/>
    </p>
    <p class="exclusiveSelection">
        Selection Two
        <input type="radio" name="firstColumn"/>
        <input type="radio" name="secondColumn"/>
    </p>
    <p class="exclusiveSelection">
        Selection Three
        <input type="radio" name="firstColumn"/>
        <input type="radio" name="secondColumn"/>
    </p>
    <input type="button" id="submitForm" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".exclusiveSelection input[type='radio']").click(function() {
        $exclusiveSelection = $(this).parent();
        $('input[type='radio']', $exclusiveSelection).attr('checked', false);
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    });
});
```

It ensures that the values are unique across column and row and works with jQuery 1.2.6 - 1.7.1. There is also a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mJNn2/).

If you need help adapting this for Rails let me know, however it should be straight forward.

Comment: this is *very* helpful…Thank you! The functionality is exactly what I'm looking for!  Now, not sure if you can help with this too, but I'd like to alter the actual radio buttons themselves so they look "better", perhaps clickable divs?!?  (they should also work with a touch UI - though that could be separate CSS). Any thoughts?